# JavaFX - Retrieve objects from notification popups

Tags: java, javafx, push-notification, notifications

i am facing a problem with a JavaFX application i'm developing, this is how to retrieve the data i use to create the notification popup.
The case is this: i have a thread looping call against a web service every x seconds, this is returning me the data i need (which, in part, i use to create the notification).
This is a portion of the code:

```
        if(alert.isNotificationAlertEnabled()) {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {

                    System.out.println(".run()");

                    try {

                        Notifications notificationBuilder = Notifications.create()
                                                                         .title(((JSONObject) result.get(i)).get("number").toString())
                                                                         .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(Alert.NOTIFICATION_DURATION))
                                                                         .position(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT)
                                                                         .text(((JSONObject) result.get(i)).get("short_description").toString())
                                                                         .darkStyle();

                        notificationBuilder.onAction(e -> {

                            // HOW TO RETRIEVE <result[i]> HERE?

                        });
                        notificationBuilder.show();

                    } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

There is a way to bound data to the single notification in order to use them in the onAction() method?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I may not truly understand what you are trying to do but can't you do something like `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) result.get(i)).get("number").toString();` Then `Notifications notificationBuilder =.....` and `notificationBuilder.onAction(e -> {

                            // HOW TO RETRIEVE <result[i]> HERE?
                            System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
                        });
                        notificationBuilder.show();`

Comment: Are you running into a final or effectively final problem?

Comment: Yeah, that's why i asked (in the first place i already tried ur approach)

Comment: Have you tried making `JSONObject jsonObject` global.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding your question, but it seems to me you can do

```
 if(alert.isNotificationAlertEnabled()) {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println(".run()");

                try {

                    Notifications notificationBuilder = Notifications.create()
                                                                     .title(((JSONObject) result.get(i)).get("number").toString())
                                                                     .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(Alert.NOTIFICATION_DURATION))
                                                                     .position(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT)
                                                                     .text(((JSONObject) result.get(i)).get("short_description").toString())
                                                                     .darkStyle();

                    notificationBuilder.onAction(e -> {

                        // HOW TO RETRIEVE <result[i]> HERE?
                        System.out.println(((JSONObject) result.get(i)).toString());
                    });
                    notificationBuilder.show();

                } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

or

```
if(alert.isNotificationAlertEnabled()) {

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println(".run()");

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) result.get(i);
                    Notifications notificationBuilder = Notifications.create()
                                                                     .title(jsonObject.get("number").toString())
                                                                     .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(Alert.NOTIFICATION_DURATION))
                                                                     .position(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT)
                                                                     .text(jsonObject.get("short_description").toString())
                                                                     .darkStyle();

                    notificationBuilder.onAction(e -> {

                        // HOW TO RETRIEVE <result[i]> HERE?
                        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
                    });
                    notificationBuilder.show();

                } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            }
        }
    });
}
```